# Is it possible to automatically convert data from multiple traits to a single type?

Tags: rust

I have some data I'd like to prevent from logging (`PrivateData`), even on accident. But I'd still like to accept either those values or values with the `Display` trait (mostly strings but also a few `Enum`) in a function and struct. I tried implementing `Into` for `Display` and my `PrivateDisplay` traits, but it's reporting that it doesn't have a size at compile time. Is there a way to work around that or another approach that could work for this use case? I'd like to avoid requiring the programmer to wrap the types manually (e.g., `create_data(Value::PrivateDisplay(PrivateData(Box::new(String::new("test")))))`).

## Code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ad287117da4261c118b0b62cb6698039))

```rust
use std::fmt;
use std::io::Read;

trait PrivateDisplay {
    fn private_fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result;
}

struct PrivateData(String);

impl PrivateDisplay for PrivateData {
    fn private_fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}", self.0)
    }
}

enum Value {
    Display(Box<dyn fmt::Display>),
    PrivateDisplay(Box<dyn PrivateDisplay>),
}

impl Into<Value> for dyn fmt::Display {
    fn into(self) -> Value {
        Value::Display(Box::new(self))
    }
}

impl Into<Value> for dyn PrivateDisplay {
    fn into(self) -> Value {
        Value::PrivateDisplay(Box::new(self))
    }
}

struct Data {
    value: Value,
}

fn create_data<V>(value: V) -> Data
where
    V: Into<Value>
{
    Data {
        value: value,
    }
}

fn main() {
    create_data("test");
    create_data(PrivateData(String::from("test")));
    
    // May also be data provided from outside program
    let mut buffer = String::from("buffer");
    std::io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    create_data(buffer);
}
```

## Errors:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/main.rs:20:6
    |
21  | impl Into<Value> for dyn fmt::Display {
    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::fmt::Display + 'static)`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn PrivateDisplay + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/main.rs:26:6
    |
27  | impl Into<Value> for dyn PrivateDisplay {
    |      ^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn PrivateDisplay + 'static)`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: could not compile `playground`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Comment: Does changing your `dyn` to a reference work? `impl Into<Value> for &dyn fmt::Display`

Comment: @BallpointBen that adds a bunch of lifetime requirements that I can't seem to get to work.

Comment: I think what you really want is something like `impl<T: fmt::Display> From<T> for Value { fn from(t: T) -> Self { Value::Display(Box::new(t)) } }`, but that would cause conflicting implementations when you implement the version for `PrivateDisplay`.  It's conflicting because it's possible for someone else to write a new type that implements both `fmt::Display` and `PrivateDisplay`, in which case it isn't possible to tell which conversion to use.  [Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f556ce66898176c572ec9e4c8db61b44).

Comment: @Bernard Could you explain why `impl <T: fmt::Display> From <T>` does something different from `impl From <fmt::Display>`? [I was able to tweak your version a bit](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f45f0c197fd976f46db4b032f24ab79) to get it to work with just `Display`, but like you said, having both would run into a conflict. While [doing it the second way](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5ad7142b259cfeaa3b0a71dd331f876a) gets away from the conflict, but still has the compile-time size issue.

Comment: That's because `fmt::Display` is a trait, not a type.  `impl<T: fmt::Display> From<T> for Value` roughly means "for any type `T` that satisfies trait `fmt::Display`, `Value` satisfies the trait `From<T>` (i.e. `T` can be convert into `Value`)".  Since `fmt::Display` is not a type, it doesn't make sense to say `Value` satisfies the trait `From<fmt::Display>`.  (Saying "`fmt::Display` can be converted into `Value`" doesn't make sense, but saying "any type that satisfies `fmt::Display` can be converted into `Value`" does.

Comment: However, `impl From<Box<dyn fmt::Display>> for Value` does make sense, because `Box<dyn fmt::Display>` is a type, not a trait.  (It is a type that allows storage of any object that satisfies `fmt::Display`, at the cost of one indirection / heap allocation at runtime.)

Answer (score 0):

As [mentioned by @Bernard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68896490/is-it-possible-to-automatically-convert-data-from-multiple-traits-to-a-single-ty?noredirect=1#comment121762654_68896490) in the comments, the compile time size issue can be worked around with `impl<T: 'static + fmt::Display> From<T> for Value`, but it will result in [conflicting implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159226/conflicting-implementations-of-trait-in-rust) because of the generic type `T`. It may be able to adjust this code to work once [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) is merged.

Until then, if you're able to replace one of the traits with a type instead, it can work ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1153eb5b010122249c2da649909fff03)):

```rust
use std::fmt;
use std::io::Read;

struct PrivateData(String);

enum Value {
    Display(Box<dyn fmt::Display>),
    PrivateDisplay(Box<PrivateData>),
}

impl Value {
    fn as_string(self) -> String {
        match self {
            Value::Display(display) => format!("{}", display),
            Value::PrivateDisplay(private) => format!("{}", private.0),
        }
    }
}

impl<T: 'static + fmt::Display> From<T> for Value {
    fn from(t: T) -> Self {
        Value::Display(Box::new(t))
    }
}

impl Into<Value> for PrivateData {
    fn into(self) -> Value {
        Value::PrivateDisplay(Box::new(self))
    }
}

struct Data {
    value: Value,
}

fn create_data<V>(value: V) -> Data
where
    V: Into<Value>
{
    Data {
        value: value.into(),
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", create_data("str").value.as_string());
    println!("{}", create_data(PrivateData(String::from("string"))).value.as_string());
    
    // May also be data provided from outside program
    let mut buffer = String::from("buffer");
    std::io::stdin().read_to_string(&mut buffer).unwrap();
    println!("{}", create_data(buffer).value.as_string());
}
```

Comment: It's better to do [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=628b84d0f3aee7e03fdb66cf86ef6ae0) instead.  Firstly, it's preferable to implement `From` instead of `Into` (see the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html)).  Secondly, we don't need a Box for Value::PrivateDisplay since PrivateData is a type (with known size) - the Box is necessary for Value::Display only because we want to be able to store _any_ type that implements fmt::Display (which means that at compile time we can't know the space that this object needs).

Comment: @Bernard thanks so much for all of that explanation!