# Conflicting implementation of trait (generics)

Tags: rust, traits

```rust
// std::cmp::PartialOrd is required for the comparison with T::zero(), but Complex does not implement it
impl<T> std::fmt::Display for Polynomial<T>
where
    T: Num + Clone + std::ops::Neg<Output = T> + std::cmp::PartialOrd + std::fmt::Display,
{
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        let mut formatted_string: String = String::new();
        let mut is_first_term: bool = true;

        for (degree, coefficient) in self.coefficients.iter().enumerate().rev() {
            if coefficient != &T::zero() {
                let mut coefficient: T = coefficient.clone();
                let is_neg: bool = coefficient < T::zero();
                let sign: &str = if is_neg {
                    coefficient = -coefficient;
                    "- "
                } else {
                    "+ "
                };

                if is_first_term {
                    if is_neg {
                        formatted_string.push_str(sign);
                    }
                    is_first_term = false;
                } else {
                    formatted_string.push(' ');
                    formatted_string.push_str(sign);
                }

                let formatted: String = match degree {
                    0 => format!("{}", coefficient),
                    1 => format!("{}x", coefficient),
                    _ => format!("{}x^{}", coefficient, degree),
                };

                formatted_string.push_str(&formatted);
            }
        }

        write!(f, "{}", formatted_string)
    }
}

// Why does this not work?
impl std::fmt::Display for Polynomial<num::Complex<f64>> {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        // Implement custom formatting for Polynomial<num::Complex<f64>> here
        write!(f, "Your custom formatting for Complex<f64> polynomials")
    }
}
```

Complete code: https://pastebin.com/Cari6TWF

Error message:
`` conflicting implementations of trait `std::fmt::Display` for type `Polynomial<num::Complex<f64>>` upstream crates may add a new impl of trait `std::cmp::PartialOrd` for type `num::Complex<f64>` in future versions ``

Because `Complex<T>` doesn't implement `std::cmp::PartialOrd` I didn't expect the second `impl` to interfere with the first one.

I looked into the following answer as well: [Conflicting implementations of trait in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159226/conflicting-implementations-of-trait-in-rust) but it doesn't seem to help as I need to implement it specifically for `Complex<T>`

Comment: `Complex<T>` might not `impl PartialOrd` right now, but what happens if it does in the future? (as the error says) This is why you're not allowed to do this. You might be able to hack around it using [`specialization`, but that is an unstable feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844)